# Finding the project root from within a composer package

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to provide potential locations of a config file within my package: `.config.yml`

At present, I've loaded an array within one of my classes with some typical locations:

```
protected $configDirectories = [
    './',
    './config',
    './app/config',
    './config',
    './vendor/name/packagename/config'
];
```

Problem is; my package is loaded into `./vendor/name/packagename` and of course, `./` doesn't know how to get to the project root.

The aim is to allow users of this package to just drop `.config.yml` into any of the pre-specified directories and it should be picked up. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar situation.  In my case, the front-end controller was in `./`.  So, I required the user of my package to do something like ...

```
\Wonderful\Package\Init::setRootDirectory(__DIR__);
```

(But I eventually decided that instead of having magic search order happening under the covers to locate the config file, I ended up having the one (or more) config files specified explicitly (can be anywhere with any name) ...

```
\Wonderful\Package\Init::loadConfigFile(__DIR__.'/config.yml');
\Wonderful\Package\Init::loadConfigFile(__DIR__.'/config.DEV-overrides.yml');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to give the user the ability to configure your bundle, you MUST do it via [semantic configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html) and not via a specified and own config file. Do it the Symfony way.